# How to create class instance dynamically in dart for assigning List

Tags: class, flutter, dart, instance

Pls help me for creating instance of class dynamically and adding to the List in Dart program.
below is the code

```
  class FormInput {

      String id;
      String value;

      FormInput({this.id,this.value});
    }

    void main(){

      List<FormInput> formInputs = [];  

      FormInput formInput = new FormInput();  

      formInput.id = '3';
      formInput.value = 'test';

      formInputs.add(formInput);

      formInput.id = '4';
      formInput.value = 'test1';

      formInputs.add(formInput);

      print(formInputs[0].id);
      print(formInputs[0].value);
      print(formInputs[1].id);
      print(formInputs[1].value); 
}
```

**Result**

4
test1
4
test1

**Expected result;**

3
test
4
test1

Thanks,
Shan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the constructor of your class.

```
formInputs.add(FormInput(id: '3', value: 'test'));
formInputs.add(FormInput(id: '4', value: 'test1'));
```